A good learning resource on finite semimodular lattices?
I'm currently doing a project tangentially related to finite semimodular lattices, and I catch myself consistently unable to "get" them. I know that the classic definition (by covering) is equivalent with Mac Lane's conditions and M-symmetry in the finite case; I've tried to prove this myself as an exercise, but failed.
I'd greatly appreciate any good entry-level resource into those lattices, with proofs of those and other basic properties clearly shown. All suggestions are very welcome!

Have looked at Grätzer's General Lattice Theory? Chapter IV is Modular and Semimodular Lattices. Another possible good resource is Stern's Semimodular Lattices, but I don't have access to this one (I had, some years ago, and I think it's a good resource, but I can't remember very well).
